# How to prove the following inequalities.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

The first inequality is

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \leq a(\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx) $ for $0<a<1$ and

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \geq a(\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx)$ for $a>1$

The second inequality is

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \leq (\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx)^a $ for $0<a<1$ and

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \geq (\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx)^a$ for $a>1$

where $f(x)$ is a probability density function and $x>0$.

Could the first or second inequlaity be able to prove?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first inequalities are not true: suppose $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. Then for $0<a<1$,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^af(x)dx=\int_0^{1} x^adx\geq \int_0^1 xdx=\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx> a\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx
$$
and similarly, for $a>1$,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^a f(x)=\int_0^1 x^a dx\leq \int_0^1 xdx =\int_0^{\infty} x f(x)dx<a\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx.
$$

The second inequalities however are true, and follow immediately from Jensen's Theorem: when $0<a<1$ the map $x\mapsto x^a$ is concave and so thinking of $f(x)$ as the PDF of some nonnegative random variable $X$:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^af(x)dx=\mathbb{E}[X^a]\leq \mathbb{E}[X]^a=\bigg(\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx\bigg)^{\alpha}.
$$
Similarly, when $1<a$, the map $x\mapsto x^a$ is convex and so 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^af(x)dx=\mathbb{E}[X^a]\geq \mathbb{E}[X]^a=\bigg(\int_0^{\infty} xf(x)dx\bigg)^{\alpha}.
$$

Comment: "$u^a-au<0$ when $0<a<1$" is not true, take $a=1/2$ and plot this on Wolfram. Your other claim is false for when $a>1$, take $a=2$ and plot it as a function of $u$.

Comment: I just got it, thanks for your reply.

Comment: if i change the first one like this  $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx $ for $0<a<1$ and

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^af(x)dx \geq \int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x)dx$ for $a>1$ , is this correct?

Comment: No, if you follow the steps of my examples these still fail. I wrote weak inequalities in the intermediate steps but they are actually strict.